# .vimrc map base on file type

Tags: php, python, bash, vim

i am using vim for coding on remote server and i have html, js, css, py and php script that i use and for the php and py i want to be able to map a ctrl key to validate them.

i would like to map `ctrl_p` to a `php -l` for php script and "pylint" for python

right now i have this:

```
map <C-P> :!php -l %<CR>
```

how to check what file i have to run

> pylint on .py files

and

> php -l on php files

with 1 key map?

Comment: What is the question? You want the same key to run a different command, based on the file that's loaded?

Comment: @miken32 yes that is what I want